# Kafka Stream - How Elastic Scaling works

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I was reading about Kafka Stream -  Elastic Scaling features.

Means Kafka Stream can handover the task to other instance and task states will get created using changelog. Its mentioned that Instance coardinate with each other to achieve rebalance.

But there is no such detail given how exactly rebalance work?

Is it same like how Consumer Group works or different mechanism because Kafka Stream instances not exactly how consumer in Consumer Group?

Comment: Kafka Streams applications do form a consumer group.

Comment: How it rebalance state with task attached to partition...I read it uses changelog how it get replicated?

Comment: Did you check out the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html?  -- Task, or actually their stores (ie, the corresponding shard) write into changelog topic. When an input partition and thus, the corresponding task is migrated, before processing start the changelog to read to recreate the store.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/elastic-scaling-in-kafka-streams/) for a more thorough explanation.

..."In a nutshell, running instances of your application will automatically become aware of new instances joining the group, and will split the work with them; and vice versa, if any running instances are leaving the group (e.g. because they were stopped or they failed), then the remaining instances will become aware of that, too, and will take over their work. More specifically, when you are launching instances of your Streams API based application, these instances will share the same Kafka consumer group id.  The group.id is a setting of Kafka’s consumer configuration, and for a Streams API based application this consumer group id is derived from the application.id setting in the Kafka Streams configuration."...